# express-validator optional fields

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I got this form with optional email and I'm using express-validator to make a server side validation.

When I submit, it's suposed to validate and then process the data to save it.

routes/users.js

```
router.post('/save', users.validationRules(), users.save)
```

controllers/usersController.js

```
usersController.validationRules = () => {
  return [
    // ...
    // Some other validation rules that works
    // ...
    check('email', 'You need a valid Email')
        .optional()
        .isEmail(),
    // ... More validation rules that also works ...
  ]
}

usersController.save = (req, res) => {

    let errors = validationResult(req)

    console.log(errors);
}
```

It shows me the error message like if it were ignoring the `optional()` method. Do you guys have any idea about what is happening or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use `.optional({ checkFalsy: true })` to check against falsy values (eg "", 0, false, null).

More about it from the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions)